# magento 2 utilizing the CPU 100%

Tags: magento2.1.5

i'm using a dedicated server with SSD and 16gb memory and 2.4 8 cores server and plesk panel, php7 with apache server.

fresh magento 2.1.5 installation, any click or request on the store makes magento utilizing the CPU 99 or 100% which makes the server hung and the store also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experienced this on my local machine, it was when caching was disabled so my first port of call would be to make sure all caches are enabled.

Also make sure you're running in production mode (if it's a production server) as when in developer mode a lot of code is generated on the fly.

Comment: If you're still in developer mode enable all caches except full page cache.

Comment: By enabling cache i've got it under control. thx

Answer (score -2):

In addition, have you configured your infrastructure? There are major gains to be had through database tweaks, use of php-fpm, Zend opcache...